# Keep sqlite database after installing newer version

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am creating an to-do list iphone app and facing a problem related to version update.

During each Build & Debug process, I discovered that the my last testing data is all gone. It's fine for development and testing but how about once the app is published and when I publish a new version update? I would like my users to keep their previously to-do list.

I am using sqlite3.h to manipulate the database. When the app starts, it executes "CREATE IF EXISTS MY_TABLE" so I can guarantee there's a usable database table.

Edited:
thanks @JP reply, my issue is solved by modifying like:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filename = @"todo.db";
NSString *filepath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filname];
```

previously, my code is:

```
NSString *filename = @"todo.db";
NSString *filepath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filname];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are creating the sqlite database in the `<Application_Home>/Documents` directory, the file will be backed up by iTunes and kept across app updates.

Details are in the iOS Application Programming Guide in sections ["Backup and Restore"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW1) and ["A Few Important Application Directories"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW12)